# CSS items not rendering properly

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sortable list in which sorting features will be in left column and right column will contain the list items (the items are blocks with some information)

I have written following code :

HTML :

```
<div id="container" style="width:auto;">
        <div id="item-menu">
        Sort items by :  </div>
        <div id="content-items">
            <div id="item"> content</div>
            <div id="item"> content</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#item-menu {
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px dotted #333333;
}

#content-itemss {
    float:left;
    padding-left:20px;
    width:85%;
}

#item {
    display:block;
    background:#333;
    border:1px dotted #000000;
    color:#FFF;
    width:inherit;
    margin:10px 10px;
    padding:10px 10px;
}
```

However, the list items somehow end up messing with the layout. Here's the screenshot..
[image: Items are not going in the right part where they should]

How to correct this? Also, is there any easy way like some WYSIWYG editor for such CSS designs?

Comment: you have multiple `id`'s. use `class="item"`. an `id` must be unique. Also you have double `s` in `#content-itemss`

Comment: And you have a typo: `id="content-items"` in your HTML and `#content-itemss` in your CSS

Comment: Correcting the typo didn't rectify the error. Also, when I will change `id` to class, will I have to change `#` to `.` in CSS?

Comment: Yes you have to change it to `.`. What should it look like?

Comment: I changed all `#`s to `.`s and all `id`s to `class`es. Still the problem persists..

Comment: @tigerden please provide a jsfiddle link so tht we can help you better

Comment: @tigerden, can you explain / show what it should look like? We can't tell from your question.

Comment: is this how you want it to look? http://jsfiddle.net/dHc8W/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6qQzb/ Here is the link. What I mean is, there is a dotted border to the right of 'sort items by'. All the content blocks should appear to the right of border, looking like they are in right column of a two-column table. currently they are appearing below 'sort items by' text.

Comment: @ashley yes, I wanted this

Comment: @tigerden accept the answer then the question will be complete

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the layout you wanted, I changed the `box-model` to `border-box` which means that padding given to an element becomes part of it's width. (http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

I added a `clearfix` class to parent elements that hold floated children, because this causes the parent to collapse. (http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHc8W/

Code:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.clear:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#item-menu {
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px dotted #333333;
}

#content-items {
    float:left;
    padding-left:20px;
    width:85%;
}

.item {
    background:#333;
    border:1px dotted #000000;
    color:#FFF;
    width:inherit;
    margin:10px 10px;
    padding:10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: It is rendering properly in Chrome and JSFiddle but not in Firefox, why is this?

Comment: @tigerden sorry. you need to add browser prefix: `-moz-box-sizing`. To make sure it works for others, just add `-webkit-`, this will work for safari also.

`-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

These may or may not work depending on how you want the 'content' to display.
But as far as I can tell with the given code they give the desired result.
You'll probably want to adjust the `padding:` and `margin:` if you want it flush with the top.

**Solution #1**

This method will behave strangely if the actual content is greater than the `max-width:`.
Works with smaller content.

**CSS**

```
#content-items {
float:left;
padding-left:20px;
max-width:85%;   /*changed to 'max-width'*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sP6t2/

**Solution #2**  *(suggested method)*

if you want the content to always be longer, decreasing to `width:84%` will bump up the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/sP6t2/1/